# Как работает в данном случае str_replace php?

Tags: php

Как то давно я делал многоязычность c помощью php. И когда очередь дошла до кнопок переключалок языка, мне посоветовали следующий код:

```
<?php
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $url .= (strpos($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&');
?>
```

```
<a href="<?=$url . 'lang=en'?>"><img class="lang" src="images/langen.png"></a>
<a href="<?=$url . 'lang=ru'?>"><img class="lang r" src="images/langrus.png"></a>
```

Вроде все работало, но визуально было некрасиво. Если бы мы переключали на одной странице языки несколько раз, то субдомены (или как оно называется) накладывались бы бесконечно друг на друга.

```
mysite.com/index.php?lang=ru&lang=en&lang=ru&lang=en&lang=ru
```

И тогда я начал искать, то как не добавить новый `lang`, а заменить и нашел функцию `str_replace('','','')`.

```
<?php
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $url = str_replace('','','');
?>
```

```
<a href="<?=$url . '?lang=en'?>"><img class="lang" src="images/langen.png"></a>
<a href="<?=$url . '?lang=ru'?>"><img class="lang r" src="images/langrus.png"></a>
```

Я оставил все ее значения пустыми, но она работает, один `lang` заменяется на другой, а не накладывается. И у меня возник вопрос, как так она работает или это случайность? Как я понял, она просто стирает предыдущий элемент, но в полях ничего не указано, как она поняла, что нужно убрать?

А так же какие альтернативы решения данного случая?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Оно работает, как `$url = '';` https://3v4l.org/I9vlf  Так что просто удалите его из шаблона =)

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо, там по сути весь скрипт можно удалить, работает и без него)
Можете оформить как ответ, галочку поставлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как отметил @vp_arth эта функция срабатывает, как обычная пустая строка `$url = '';`.
Поэксперементировав, оказалось что весь cкрипт вообще не нужен:

```
<?php
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $url = str_replace('','','');
?>
```

Его можно удалить, но нужно отредактировать ссылки и убрать лишнее и все будет работать:

```
<a href="?lang=en"><img class="lang" src="images/langen.png"></a>
<a href="?lang=ru"><img class="lang" src="images/langrus.png"></a>
```